# Desktop Shortcut to open new chrome web page as new tab

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to open a directly new tab like `"chrome://newtab"` from desktop shortcut.

I tried change it a webpage shortcut to google.com but it has a respond time.

Edit: Normally chrome has a default setting but i can't change it due to Administration. They changed my startup web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new shortcut using:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome://newtab

:)